# How do I use SANs with openSSL instead of common name?

Tags: openssl

After upgrading a system (kubernetes) that uses golang 1.15.0-rc.1, I am stuck on this error message:

```
"x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs or temporarily enable Common Name matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0".
```

The only place I am using common name (that I know of) is when I generate the private key for my service `openssl req -new -key certs/foo-bar.pem -subj "/CN=foobar.mydomain.svc" -out certs/foo-bar.csr -config certs/foo-bar_config.txt`.

How can I convert this command to use SANs instead?

Comment: I should clarify, I understand what the difference between the two is, but I can't figure out from googling/reading articles what the syntax is to implement the switch.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may need the `-addext` flag.

For example:

```
openssl req -new -key certs/foo-bar.pem \
    -subj "/CN=foobar.mydomain.svc" \
    -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:foobar.mydomain.svc" \
    -out certs/foo-bar.csr \
    -config certs/foo-bar_config.txt
```

Got the answer from here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-the-command-line

Comment: Only freaking way I had to make the SAN thing work. Security by sorcery!

1. `SAN` env var : didn't work
2. `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` -> `subjectAltName=${ENV::SAN}` : didn'twork

The command to make it work (OpenSSL 1.1.1f, but trust me, your openssl won't do the same) was:

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -x509 -days 365 -out server.crt -subj "/CN=localhost" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost"`

Now the example https://posener.github.io/http2/ works for me without `GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0`, self-signed, no "State or province", no nothing. Take that!

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips complains about an unknown option -addext. Not claiming that version is new, but it seems the current one for CentOS 7.

Comment: Found out missing part from the recommendations and accepted answer:
you also need to copy extensions from cert req into final certificate.

For doing that consider to use option

    -copy_extensions copyall

Answer (score 32):

**Solution**

I explained totally.

This solution **works** for me. At first you must have a CA and then sign your server cert by CA. I create a CA and server cert and finally sign server cert by command bellow.(change your desired -subj and CN)

In your situation you should pass the subjectAltName when you signing server cert in latest command line below.

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Acme, Inc./CN=Acme Root CA" -out ca.crt

openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Acme, Inc./CN=*.example.com" -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com") -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt
```

After run this command you can use certs (server.crt,servert.key) in kubernetes secret for ingress.

Comment: This worked with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips (which doesn't support the -addext option)

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, openssl version OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, in bash -extfile < ( .. syntax does not work. I just created 

`$ echo "subjectAltName=DNS:some.host" > altsubj.ext`
`$ openssl x509 -req -extfile altsubj.ext ...`

Then it worked fine.

Comment: thanks for this batteries-included answer without any blurry parts. much better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196866/589493 of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196502/failed-to-connect-to-a-server-with-golang-due-x509-certificate-relies-on-legacy (which is unrelated to MongoDB btw)

Comment: TIL: 1) SANs(extensions) aren't copied over from the CSR. 2) You can skip writing out to a file: `-extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com")` . You can use `/dev/stdout` to pipe the CSR to cert signing `openssl req  ... -out /dev/stdout | openssl x509 ... `. Remove the -in server.csr from the last command.

Answer (score 3):

I think this blog post will help you, [Know about SAN Certificate and How to Create With OpenSSL](https://geekflare.com/san-ssl-certificate/). Otherwise you could made what is suggested by the error message, and set `GODEBUG="x509ignoreCN=0"` as a environment variable.

Comment: I just add GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0 as an environment variable and the error message remains the same.

Comment: For me it works, but it's just a docker swarm usecase. Not at first, because the env variable was not on the right place

Comment: Thanks for this hint. The error message does not say it should be an environment variable. And the recommended "see docker run --help" does not either...

Comment: GODEBUG="x509ignoreCN=0" flag deprecated in go 1.17

Answer (score 1):

I run on redhat 8.4 using environment varialbe, it works for me

```
export GODEBUG="x509ignoreCN=0"
podman login repo.example.com:5000
```

Username: registryuser
Password:
Login Succeeded!

Comment: That's not solution. It's hidding problems...