# Get "https://zzzztower.zzzz.com/api/v2/hosts/": x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead

Tags: api, go, ssl, x509certificate, ca

I am trying to get the list of hosts from ansible tower using the API defined in [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.8.5/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/)
I am using the ansible tower URL ->  https://zzzztower.zzzz.com/api/v2/hosts/
and the bearer token -> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
to hit the API.

When I use postman to hit the API I am getting a proper response
but when I use golang code, I am getting error

> Get "https://ansibletower.micron.com/api/v2/hosts/": x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead

Here is my code:

```
package globals

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

// var AUTH_TOKEN string = os.Getenv("AUTH_TOKEN")

func GetAnsibleHosts() (string, error) {

    url := "https://zzzztower.zzzz.com/api/v2/hosts/"
    method := "GET"

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Error creating request: %v", err)
    }

    bearerToken := "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

    // Add the Bearer Auth token to the request
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+bearerToken)

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return "", err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return "", err
    }
    // fmt.Println(string(body))
    return string(body), err
}
```

I tried finding the error on google but i didn't find much help.
Few articles mentioned to use `GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0` but it didn't worked.

I would really appreciate you help.

Comment: Get a new certificate for that host. You can't connect to it with a recent version of Chrome either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use SANs with openSSL instead of common name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814173/how-do-i-use-sans-with-openssl-instead-of-common-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip this check, we can use `InsecureSkipVerify` and set it to **true**.

Something like this:

```
// Create a new transport with InsecureSkipVerify set to true
transport := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}

// Create a new client using the transport
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

And then this `client` can be used to get the response.

PS: This worked for me but others pls suggest a better approach if any.