Gitlab Runner archive error: no such host
I encountered following issue:
I have 2 docker containers: one for my gitlab instance and one for my runner. Both are on the same host and even in the same docker network. However pulling and executing scripts are working fine, but as soon as i try to use artifacts i run into a connection error. The strange thing about it is that the ip address is nowhere related to my server its a recursive dns service from my hosting provider hetzner. My runner compose.yml
services:
  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    container_name: runner
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy-network

networks:
  proxy-network:
    name: proxy-network
    external: true

my config.toml:
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner"
  url = "http://gitlab"
  id = 1
  token = "secret"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-09-24T22:41:15Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
    network_mode = "host"

my gitlab compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'myurl'
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
          "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
          "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
        }
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2222
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '256m'
    networks:
      - proxy-network

networks:
  proxy-network:
    name: proxy-network
    external: true

i tried so much but i cant overcome this error:
$ echo "Building ..."
Building ...
$ mkdir -p build
$ touch build/somefile.txt
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:03
Uploading artifacts...
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against http://gitlab:80/api/v4/jobs/27/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive: Post "http://gitlab:80/api/v4/jobs/27/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive": dial tcp: lookup gitlab on 185.12.64.2:53: no such host id=27 token=glcbt-64
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

the actual runner gives me this information:
Running on runner-tj6qbzsfw-project-2-concurrent-0 via 77f500501b11...

Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...

Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/developer/test/.git/

fatal: unable to access 'someurl': Failed to connect to myurl port 443 after 130582 ms: Could not connect to server

Im using the nginx proxy manager btw to redirect for my several services maybe i made a mistake there.

i tried to change to localhost as gitlab url or append ports nothing changes
i tried to change the mtu nothing changes
i read the documentation again if i made a mistake setting the runner up but even after a reinstallation same issue


It seems like the job tries to resolve the dns but i don't have a entry for port 443 only for port 80.

I found a fix, i had to use https and encountered ssl cert trust issues but this post here helped me fix it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814173/how-do-i-use-sans-with-openssl-instead-of-common-name
